# Snowflake functions including javascript return NULL

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This piece of JS works fine when debugging in the console, but when I place it within a Snowflake function, it returns NULL. I've replaced the contents of the JS function with a simple `return 'string';` and that works.  What am I missing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LSETL.PUBLIC.GET_RAND_LNAME()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
function generateRandomName() {
  const lastNames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown", "Taylor"];
  const randomLastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
  return `${randomLastName}`;
}
$$;
```

`SELECT LSETL.PUBLIC.GET_RAND_LNAME();`  =  NULL

Expected behavior is for the Snowflake function to return a randomly selected last name via the JS code.  I have tried executing the JS outside of the function (it works) and executing the function with much simpler JS (it works.)  I have also carefully examined my life choices up to this point.

-- EDIT --

adding a return of the JS function to the UDF unfortunately also results in a NULL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LSETL."PUBLIC".get_rand_lname()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
function generateRandomName() {
  const lastNames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown"];
  const randomLastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
  return `${randomLastName}`;
}
return generateRandomName();
 
$$;
```

Comment: The edited version works for me. It may be calling an old copy of the function (it's owned by a database and schema). See my note below about checking the body of the function using get_ddl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no lines of code in the main section of the UDF. The `function generateRandomName()` part is a helper function, which won't run until you call it. You can either do this to call the helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LSETL.PUBLIC.GET_RAND_LNAME()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
return generateRandomName(); // Call generateRandomName and return results
function generateRandomName() {
  const lastNames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown", "Taylor"];
  const randomLastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
  return `${randomLastName}`;
}
$$;
```

Alternatively, you can change the code to be in the main section with no helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LSETL.PUBLIC.GET_RAND_LNAME()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS $$
  const lastNames = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Brown", "Taylor"];
  const randomLastName = lastNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * lastNames.length)];
  return `${randomLastName}`;
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for those examples, my UDF was indeed missing any  way to return the results of the JS back to Snowflake.  I think that may not be my only problem though, because I just tried both of  your suggested methods but still got a NULL result when executing `SELECT LSETL."PUBLIC".GET_RAND_LNAME();`

Comment: Both samples returned a random last name for me. Perhaps the `create or replace` created it somewhere else? What happens when you run `select get_ddl('function','LSETL."PUBLIC".GET_RAND_LNAME()');` Does it still have the old code?

Comment: Ok thank you for confirming and putting me ont the right track.  The problem was Dbeaver actually, instead of executing the DDL I wrote, it was popping up a "bind parameters" panel which I just foolishly clicked through since my function had no parameters.  When I did a select to see the actual DDL, I saw it was actually overwriting the return portion of the function with return ('NULL').  I re-created the function directly from a snowflake worksheet and now it's fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your javascript function within the UDF might be returning something (to the body of the UDF) but your UDF isn’t returning anything to Snowflake. If you want to code this as a javascript function within your UDF (which is probably unnecessary) then your UDF needs to contain code to call this function and the return the value. If you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction) (section called “Variant, Objects, and Arrays”) you can see it contains a function:

```
function flatten(input)
```

and later this function is called and it’s value returned:

```
return flatten(V);
```